# Rendering only the specific component on Select option change. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a react app which will fetch the api using the values from the url params. which are modified using navigate prop without page refresh.

Here is the code.

```
const App = () => {

    const [itemData, setItemData] = useState({});
    const [itemError, setItemError] = useState({});
    const [additionalData, setAdditionalData] = useState({});
    const [additionalError, setAdditionalError] = useState({});
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [showTrailer, setShowTrailer] = useState(false);
    const [trailer, setTrailer] = useState({});
    const [trailerError, setTrailerError] = useState({});
    const [group, setGroup] = useState([])

    const backend_url = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND;

    const handleCloseTrailer = () => setShowTrailer(false);
    const handleShowTrailer = () => setShowTrailer(true);

    const location = useLocation();
    const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];

    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
    const [groupId, setGroupId]  = useState(searchParams.get("group_id"));

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function handleChange(value) {
        navigate(`?group_id=${value}`);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMainApi = () => {
            setIsLoading(true)
            axios.get(`${backend_url}/api/v1/metadata?id=${id}`)
            .then(function(response) {
                if(response.data.content.apiId !== 'undefined') {
                    axios.get("API_URL")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        setAdditionalData(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        setAdditionalError(error);
                    })
                }
                if(itemData && (itemData.apiId !== 'null' || 'undefined')) {
                    axios.get("API_URL")
                    .then(function(response) {
                        setTrailer(response.data)
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        setTrailerError(error)
                    })
                }
                if(type === "cat" && itemData.children) {
                    setGroup(itemData.children)
                }
                if(type === "cat" && itemData.children)
                axios.get("API_URL" + groupId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    setPeople(response.data.content.children);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
                setItemData(response.data.content)
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                setItemError(error)
            })
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
        fetchMainApi()
    }, [backend_url,id,type,itemData.apiId,itemData.api])

    return (
        <>
            <Form.Select onChange={event => handleChange(event.target.value)} aria-label="Default select example">
                <option>Group All</option>
                {cluster.map((person, index) => (
                    <option key={guid()} value={group.id}>{group.name}</option>
                ))}
            </Form.Select>
            <People people={people}/>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the People component

```
const People = ({people}) => {
    return (
        <Row className="m-2 pt-2">
            <h2 className="color-white">People</h2>
            {people && people.length > 0 && (people.map((people, index) => (
                <Col key={index} className="p-lg-4 p-sm-3" xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} xl={3}>
                    ....
                </Col>
            )))}
            { (!people || people.length === 0) && (<h5 className="color-white">No Persons Found</h5>) }
        </Row>
    );
};

export default People;
```

Working

The select menu updates the query param and then the value of param is taken inside useEffect hook when then provides the data.

Every thing works well but the problem is to update the data inside the component i need to refresh the page when then works as expected.

Is there a way to change or update only the people component without a page refresh.

Comment: When you call `setPeople`, `<People people={people}/>` will re-render. That's the entire point of React's existence, and the reason for its name. So you need to make sure that changing the select will ultimately call setPeople and therefore cause a re-render of <People />

Comment: `setIsLoading(false)` is in a totally wrong place - it should be at the end of the `.then` or `.catch` blocks (better yet: use `.finally()`.